# How to remove a link from content in php?

Tags: php, hyperlink

How can i remove the link and remain with the text?

```
text text text. <br><a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank' title='title' style='text-decoration:none;'>name</a>
```

like this:

```
text text text. <br>
```

i still have a problem.....

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.php?id=name');
echo preg_replace('#<a.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $text)
```

in that url was that text(with the link) ...

this code doesn't work...

what's wrong?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 44):

I suggest you to keep the text in link.

```
strip_tags($text, '<br>');
```

or the hard way:

```
preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text)
```

If you don't need to keep text in the link

```
preg_replace('#<a.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $text)
```

Comment: He didn't indicate he wanted name to remain

Comment: preg_replace('#<a.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $text)            helped me

Comment: Awesome answer, you may add the `s` flag to make it work with links spanning multiple lines `preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#is', '\1', $text)`

Answer (score 4):

While `strip_tags()` is capable of basic string sanitization, it's not fool-proof. If the data you need to filter is coming in from a user, and especially if it will be displayed back to other users, you might want to look into a more comprehensive HTML sanitizer, like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). These types of libraries can save you from a lot of headache up the road.

`strip_tags()` and various regex methods can't and won't stop a user who really wants to inject something.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/<a.*?<\/a>/','',"test test testa<br> <a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank' title='title' style='text-decoration:none;'>name</a>");
```

Comment: Better use `/<a\s.*?<\/a>/` to ignore tags like `<abbr>`, `<article>`, etc

Answer (score 3):

this is my solutions :

```
function removeLink($str){
$regex = '/<a (.*)<\/a>/isU';
preg_match_all($regex,$str,$result);
foreach($result[0] as $rs)
{
    $regex = '/<a (.*)>(.*)<\/a>/isU';
    $text = preg_replace($regex,'$2',$rs);
    $str = str_replace($rs,$text,$str);
}
return $str;}
```

Answer (score 1):

A version from the above compiled notes:

```
$withoutlink = preg_replace('/<a.*>(.*)<\/a>/isU','$1',$String);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will strip HTML tags.

Comment: The question is about removing links, not the whole HTML formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Very simple!

```
$content = "text text text. <br><a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank' title='title' style='text-decoration:none;'>name</a>";
echo preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>[a-z]+/i", "", $content);
```

Output:

```
text text text. <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string = preg_replace( '@<(a)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $string );
```

Note:
this code remove link with text.

Answer (score -1):

One more short solution without regexps:

```
function remove_links($s){
    while(TRUE){
        @list($pre,$mid) = explode('<a',$s,2);
        @list($mid,$post) = explode('</a>',$mid,2);
        $s = $pre.$post;
        if (is_null($post))return $s;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Regex is much simpler, saver and by far more efficient than a while loop with string manipulation like this. Just imagine the HTML code contains `<abbr>`, then this code will possibly lose a lot of text...

Comment: agree with you.