# How to convert a clickable link in HTML into text with PHP preg_replace function

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, plaintext

Per exampe for:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

convert to

```
http://www.google.com
```

in plain text not hyperlink using preg_replace in php.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the following code:

```
$content = '<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>';
$unlinked_content = preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#is', '$1', $content);
```

I used the 's' modifier for multilined links.

But if you are trying to create an legible piece of text you must to encapsulate the unlinked content using something like `[$1]` as the second parameter of preg_replace function.

If you want to learn about regex, I recomend the [regex101](https://regex101.com/) page.

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text)
```

[How to remove a link from content in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830717/how-to-remove-a-link-from-content-in-php)