# How to remove anchor tag from META in WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

i recently install and setup website using WordPress , and i wanna remove anchor tag ( Date) ,

[as per screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMYpL.png)

i did try function filter code and its doesn't help

its doesn't work

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'removelink_content',1);

function removelink_content($content = '')
{
    preg_match_all("#<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>#i",$content, $matches);
    $num = count($matches[0]);for($i = 0;$i < $num;$i++){
        $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i] , $matches[2][$i] , $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: `preg_match()`  (regular expression) isn't good for HTML ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128761)), use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Comment: [Answer use `DOMDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881290/128761), another similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084565/php-remove-the-links-and-content), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830717/how-to-remove-a-link-from-content-in-php)

Comment: could you please give me working code ?  im not expert .. only google and trying remove that date

Comment: It is already in the answers in those links if you read it.

Comment: Can you add your installation /web link ?

Comment: That post date is not a part of the content. You'll have to modify the theme template to remove that post-date tag or just hide using CSS.

Comment: Yes but i have to remove that anchor tag entirely becoz of SEO Purpose

Comment: here is weblink https://www.workerscompensationattorneysandiego.net/about/blog-articles/